# Tuning java process: stack, gc

Tags: java, hbase

The read & write requests are spread equally across all hbase-regions. But sometimes the cpu load on a Hbase server goes ~100% and that starts slowing down reads on that particular server. I've allocated 16GB RAM to hbase-region server.

I suspect it is GC issue. Here is the stat from busy server[1] and a normal server[2].

- FGCT & GCT seems high on the busy server. Are these numbers too high to cause the load ?
- If yes, what would be the solution to resolve this ? Decrease/Increase Java Heap memory ?

Thank you!

[1]

```
sudo /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/jstat -gc 21437 1000
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
38336.0 38336.0 3304.2  0.0   306688.0 97526.1  16393856.0  789479.9  58928.0 35296.4 672020 9114.688 1979   434.125 9548.812
38336.0 38336.0 2227.9  0.0   306688.0 130293.0 16393856.0  793799.9  58928.0 35296.4 672039 9114.927 1979   434.125 9549.052
38336.0 38336.0 1836.9  0.0   306688.0   0.0    16393856.0  794504.9  58928.0 35296.4 672057 9115.146 1979   434.125 9549.270
38336.0 38336.0 1590.8  0.0   306688.0   0.0    16393856.0  797729.2  58928.0 35296.4 672075 9115.364 1979   434.125 9549.489
38336.0 38336.0  0.0   296.8  306688.0 140907.6 16393856.0  798642.8  58928.0 35296.4 672093 9115.568 1979   434.125 9549.692
38336.0 38336.0  0.0   5712.4 306688.0   0.0    16393856.0  800782.2  58928.0 35296.4 672110 9115.792 1980   434.131 9549.923
38336.0 38336.0 605.0   0.0   306688.0 182884.3 16393856.0  792293.6  58928.0 35296.4 672121 9115.944 1980   434.131 9550.075
```

[2]

```
sudo /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/jstat -gc 8443 1000
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
38336.0 38336.0  0.0   38336.0 306688.0 55759.8  15999468.0 2109946.3  58800.0 35257.8 114639 1349.231  505    37.439 1386.670
38336.0 38336.0  0.0   38336.0 306688.0 106544.3 15999468.0 2109946.3  58800.0 35257.8 114639 1349.231  505    37.439 1386.670
38336.0 38336.0  0.0   38336.0 306688.0 159285.2 15999468.0 2109946.3  58800.0 35257.8 114639 1349.231  505    37.439 1386.670
38336.0 38336.0  0.0   38336.0 306688.0 214269.6 15999468.0 2109946.3  58800.0 35257.8 114639 1349.231  505    37.439 1386.670
38336.0 38336.0  0.0   38336.0 306688.0 277799.3 15999468.0 2109946.3  58800.0 35257.8 114639 1349.231  505    37.439 1386.670
38336.0 38336.0 38336.0  0.0   306688.0 19230.8  15999468.0 2120279.1  58800.0 35257.8 114640 1349.273  505    37.439 1386.712
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was not a GC related problem. It was a bug in HBase (HBASE-9428) that was causing high cpu load.